# Can ActionBarActivity Implemented? Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-actionbar

I am working on a Android project in which my class extends ListActivity. The problem is , i want to implement ActionBar in my activity. I know Multiple inheritance is not allowed in android java.I have tried implementing Actionbar to my class but there was an error that a Interface us expected here.Below is my code.

```
public class AudioPlayer extends ListActivity {

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbarSetting;


    String[] songs = {"1", "2a", "3b", "4c", "5d", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"};
    int[] images = {R.raw.mp1, R.raw.mp2, R.raw.mp3, R.raw.mp4, R.raw.mp5, R.raw.mp6, R.raw.mp7, R.raw.mp8, R.raw.mp9, R.raw.mp10, R.raw.mp11, R.raw.mp12};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        toolbarSetting = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarSetting);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Music");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.gan1);

        AudioPlayerCustomAdapter adapter = new AudioPlayerCustomAdapter(this, songs, images);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(AudioPlayer.this, "hey" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

A help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Can you post the logcat error message that says interface expected?

Comment: It says i have to create Interface for ActionBarActivity.